# What is the least ordinal than cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: order-theory, set-theory, ordinal-numbers

Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ be the set of functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ patially ordered by eventual domination. Obviously, every ordinal below $\omega_1$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ using only constant functions.

What is the least ordinal than cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If one of two functions eventually dominates another, you can tell which by evaluating on integers. So the cardinality of this ordinal is at most $\mathbb R$, so an upper bound is the Hartogs function of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Certainly $\mathfrak b$, the unbounding number, can be embedded: Use functions on $\omega$, and interpolate them linearly. Also $\mathfrak b+1$ can be embedded, since for the embedding of $\mathfrak b$ we may use functions from $\omega$ into `$\{-1, -\frac12, -\frac13, \}$ etc. This can be continued..  At the moment I don't see if this gets us to everything below $\mathfrak b^+$, however.

Comment: You can do $\mathfrak{c}$: Suppose $r_\alpha$, $\alpha\lt\mathfrak{c}$ are distinct reals, if $f_\alpha$ is the characteristic function of $\lbrace r_\beta : \beta\lt\alpha\rbrace$ then this sequence is increasing under total domination. This is the best you can do for *total* domination. Assuming CH, this is also the best you can do for eventual domination because of the Erdos-Rado theorem. I'm not sure what happens if you don't assume CH.

Comment: Err... The Erdos-Rado argument only shows you can't do $(2^{\mathfrak{c}})^+$ (otherwise you can get a subsequence of length $\mathfrak{c}^+$ which is totally dominating on some tail $[n,\infty)$).

Comment: François, it is a wonderful idea, but I had interpreted the OP to be concerned with the relation: $f$ is eventually dominated by $g$, when $f(x)\lt g(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$. Can you make your example work with that notion of eventual domination? 

Comment: I think "eventual domination" is unclear: Will seems to be using $(\exists r)(\forall x \geq r)[f(x) \lt g(x)]$ and I am thinking of $(\exists r)(\forall x \geq r)[f(x) \leq g(x)]$. They are quite different in flavor...

Comment: Joel: I also think $\mathfrak{b}^+$ is best possible for that definition.

Comment: My update shows it can be $\mathfrak{c}^+$, even when this is strictly larger than $\mathfrak{b}^+$. 

Comment: @François I meant strict eventual domination: $f(x)<g(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me get things started with some simple observations.

Note that given any countable sequence of functions $f_n$, we can
by diagonalization construct a function eventually dominating all
of them, $f(x)=\max_{n\leq x}f_n(x)$. It follows that we may by
transfinite recursion construct an embedding of $\omega_1$ into
your order: at successor stages, add one to the previous function;
at limit stages, use the diagonalization just described.

So actually, since $\mathbb{R}$ is order-isomorphic to bounded
intervals of itself, we can therefore also embed $\omega_1$ into
the order many times, on top of one another. So this gives
strictly larger ordinals mapping in.

More generally, the *bounding number* $\mathfrak{b}$ is the size
of the smallest unbounded family of functions, and any family of
size less than $\mathfrak{b}$ will be bounded above. Thus, the
recursive construction actually shows that we can find an
embedding of $\mathfrak{b}$ into $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ under
eventual domination. Thus, we also get strictly larger ordinals
than $\mathfrak{b}$ embedding in, by using the bounded-interval trick again.

There are diverse independence results concerning the exact
value of $\mathfrak{b}$. Under CH, it is the same as the
continuum, of course, but when CH fails, it can be far larger than
$\omega_1$.

Using Péter's idea, once we have a map from $\mathfrak{b}$ into the order, then we may conclude that the class of ordinals that map into the order is closed under sums of length $\mathfrak{b}$. Thus, any ordinal up to $\mathfrak{b}^+$ is is order-embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ under eventual domination. So $\mathfrak{b}^+$ is a lower bound for your desired ordinal.

I guess the same idea shows that whenever an ordinal $\kappa$ embeds in, then the class of ordinals will be closed under sums of length $\kappa$, and so all ordinals up to $\kappa^+$ will also map in. Thus, the smallest ordinal not embedding in must be a cardinal, and furthermore, it must be a regular cardinal for the same reason.

**Update.**  It is relatively consistent that the answer is $\mathfrak{c}^+$, even when the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$ is very large, and much larger than $\mathfrak{b}$. The reason is that by forcing, we can undertake a very long forcing iteration of length $\kappa$ to add a dominating real at each stage, and thereby get a model with continuum $\kappa$, such that $\kappa$ embeds into the order (and so the smallest ordinal not embedding into the order is $\kappa^+$). Now, the point is that with further ccc forcing, we can make $\mathfrak{b}$ small or whatever we like, but meanwhile, we still have our old functions showing that $\kappa$ maps into the order.

Comment: Note also that it is consistent with $\text{ZF}+\neg\text{AC}$ that the answer is $\omega_1$, since it is consistent with ZF that there is no $\omega_1$-sequence of distinct reals. 

Comment: Well, thanks for accepting my answer, although I think things are not yet completely settled. We've proved $\mathfrak{b}^+$ as a lower bound on your ordinal and also proved that this is not necessarily the answer, since $\mathfrak{c}^+$ can arise even when this is larger than $\mathfrak{b}^+$. The question remains whether it can be less than $\mathfrak{c}^+$ or not, and if so, what values are possible.

Comment: Let $\mathfrak b'$ be the least ordinal that cannot be embedded into $\omega^\omega$.  Your argument really shows that $\mathfrak b'$ can be $\mathfrak c^+ > \mathfrak b$.  Perhaps the ordinal taumu wants is really $\mathfrak b'$? ($\mathfrak b'$ is clearly a lower bound. 

Comment: Goldstern, yes, I agree. But do we have any model where we get different ordinals by using $\omega^\omega$ versus $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$? 

Comment: I should have said "Perhaps $\mathfrak b^{\tau\mu}=\mathfrak b'$?" I don't know any bounds for $\mathfrak b'$ that have not been mentioned already, but $\mathfrak b'$ looks like it is better suited than $\mathfrak b^{\tau\mu}$ to be compared to other well-known cardinals characteristics, so it would be helpful to know that the two are equal. (The ccc of $\mathbb R$ makes it difficult to distinguish the two, I think.)

Comment: I agree with all that.

Answer (score 6):

One can define an eventually increasing sequence $\{f_\alpha:\alpha<\omega_1\}$ by transfinite recursion on $\alpha$. By inserting sequences in the intervals $(f_\alpha(x),f_{\alpha+1}(x))$ we can see that $\omega_1$-sums (and of course, $\omega$-sums) do not lead out of the representable ordinals. This gives that all ordinals $<\omega_2$ are representable and this is clearly sharp if CH holds, by Will's above answer. 
If CH fails, larger ordinals can be represented, if, e.g. Martin's Axiom holds.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but would you mind elaborating the “inserting sequences in the intervals”-part?

Comment: The point is that because $\mathbb{R}$ is order-isomorphic to an interval (no matter how small), you can essentially map the whole order $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ into the region between any two functions $f\lt\lt g$, with $f$ dominated by $g$. 